# `activator ~ run` doesn't work

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

When running `activator ~ run`, here is what happens:

1. When the dev server first runs, I get a message in the console saying that the server is listening on port 9000.
2. Now, when I make changes to the files and save, nothing is outputted to the console.
3. When I refresh the page, however, I see a message about reload in the console, and the browser loads.

I thought `~ run` meant re-run at every file change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your `build.sbt` file and check if it contains line like `fork in run := true` in it. If it does, delete the line or set the value to `false`.

**Why is that?**

this fork is required by Activator UI to spawn the processes, so every time, when you are starting your app from UI, it adds the line first to make sure that will exist. Anyway it causes some problems with hot reload (and also some other weird things, like app hanging, memory leaks).

Comment: I see so many problems that people seem to have fixed by disabling `fork in run`. If you're not using Activator UI, is there no downside to removing this?

Comment: @jon_wu No, `fork in run` is only for spawning processes - your app with UI

Answer (score 1):

According to [Play Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/IDE):

> Tip: You can run your application using ~run to enable direct compilation on file change. This way **scala template files** are auto discovered when you create a new template in view and auto compiled when the file changes. If you use normal run then you have to hit Refresh on your browser each time.

So it apparently only applies to Scala template files.

**EDIT**

Ryan is right, just tested it and it works also for Scala files.

Since it does not work at all with the whitespace between "~" and "run" I suppose that's not a problem as well (you quoted it with whitespace).

Comment: That's not true, Play will reload for all files.  The docs are misleading in that paragraph.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how it's supposed to work? It only says `Waiting for changes` when I press ctrl+D to get back to the console. Sorry if I come off as ignorant, I have just started learning Play and Scala, and I have no idea how `sbt` is supposed to work.

Comment: No, no worries. Problem is, I can't reproduce your issue. What is your project structure and what file were you trying to change during runtime?

Comment: I did `activator new hello-scala scala-play`, then I CD'd into the directory and typed `activator ~ run`. After your answer, I also tried `activator ~run`. However, that didn't work either. Removing the line from `build.sbt` mentioned in another answer solved that problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the console first by typing

```
activator
```

Then after the console is up you could type

```
[your-app] $ ~run
```

Usually, whenever any files changed/added. It will trigger compilation process.