# Activator 1.3.6 overwriting build.sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

Twice now, Activator (or something) has overwritten my build.sbt for a Play 2.4.4 project.  After editing a view file, I refreshed a page in my app to update everything in Eclipse. It didn't work as expected, so I restarted Activator.  Upon opening the project again, it just got stuck on 'Building Project' after compiling.  After some looking, it turns out the `build.sbt` was empty except one line :

```
fork in run := true
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817729/activator-run-doesnt-work) question, I understand Activator looks for this line and sometimes adds it, but why is it overwriting the whole file?

Update:

This continues to happen with Activator 1.3.10, and has happened in every version of Activator I've used since 1.3.6.

Comment: Throw the activator script out the window :) really, you don't need it. Follow this guide to create / migrate you app: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication#create-a-new-application-without-activator

Comment: Just `sbt tasks` or `sbt 'tasks -V'` and you will see everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have any special reasons just use SBT instead activator. Activator is only wrapper with web interface for sbt project.