# unable to debug play framwork 2.x in Scala IDE

Tags: scala, debugging, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I have a project with java & scala classes. I want to debug this project in Scala IDE.

I run this command at my application end

```
./activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

And debug in Scala IDE as **Remote Java Application** with localhost & port 9999.

It did not stop at my breakpoints.

Any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `build.sbt`

```
fork in run := true
```

I changed it to `false`. Now its working.

Comment: FYI: That's not a bug that's a feature... annoying one ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/31852671/1066240 `fork in run := true` will added to your `built.sbt` everytime when you'll open the Activator UI for the project, so remember to clean it or just stop using UI for projects in development.